# dplyr, purrr, dynamically generate/calculate new columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have the following problem. I have a data frame/tibble that has (a lot) of columns that represent a value in different years, e.g. the number of inhabitants in a city at different points in time. I want to generate now columns that give me the growth rate (see pictures attached). It should be something like using mutate() while looping over the columns. I think that should be a common task but I can't find any hint how to do it.

Edit:

A minimal example could look like this:

```
## Minimal example

library(tidyverse)

## Given data frame

df <- tibble(
        City = c("Melbourne", "Sydney", "Adelaide"),
        year_2000 = c(100, 100, 205),
        year_2001 = c(101, 100, 207),
        year_2002 = c(102, 100, 209)
        )

## Result

df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    gr_2000_2001 = year_2001/year_2000*100 - 100,
    gr_2001_2002 = year_2002/year_2001*100 - 100
  )
```

I want to find a way to automate/do the mutate command in a smart way, as I have to do it for 150 years.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sEhS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev8W8.png)

Comment: Without a reproducible example it is hard for us to help you. Maybe [this](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html) can help you in the right direction.

Comment: can you please provide your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way in this example would probably be to make your data tidy and then apply whatever formula you are using to calculate growth rates by using dplyr's `lag()`function to a data frame grouped by `City`:

```
## Minimal example
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(City = c("Melbourne", "Sydney"),
             year_2000 = c(100, 100),
             year_2001 = c(101,100),
             year_2002 = c(102, 102))

df %>%
  gather(year, value, 2:4) %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  mutate(growth = value/dplyr::lag(value,n=1))
```

The result is this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   City [2]
  City      year      value growth
  <fct>     <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Melbourne year_2000   100  NA   
2 Sydney    year_2000   100  NA   
3 Melbourne year_2001   101   1.01
4 Sydney    year_2001   100   1   
5 Melbourne year_2002   102   1.01
6 Sydney    year_2002   102   1.02
```

If you absolutely need the data in the format you provided in the screenshots, you can then apply `spread()` to reshape it into the original format. This is not generally recommended, however.

Comment: Thanks a lot tifu, I will definitively try to get it running this way.